# How can I read metadata from sas7bdat file or xpt file in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Can anybody share a code where one has to read metadata from sas7bdat or xpt file? I have code for reading data in python with the help of the sas7bdat library but unable to figure out how to get metadata from the same file.

Comment: Perhaps you could figure how to use READSTAT package from Python?  It should be able to read the metadata.  https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat

Answer (score 5):

I have released a package pyreadstat that wraps the C library readstat for python and gets you the metadata. You can also read sas7bcat files.

You would use it like this:

```
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('/path/to/a/file.sas7bdat')
```

The meta object will have the metadata you are looking for including for instance variable labels, file encoding, file label. There is a read_xport function for xpt files and read_sas7bcat for catalog files, which contain other pieces of metadata, for instance value labels to be used in combination with your sas7bdat file.

Check the complete documentation:
https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat

Comment: thanks for sharing it. I don't have access to sas files now to check this but if it works it will be a good contribution to libraries.

Comment: This package is probably the best I've used to read SAV files into Python. Thank you very much!